# Complexity in finding GCD using 2 euclid approaches

Tags: c, algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to find the gcd of two numbers using two approach one is substraction

```
    int gcd2(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return b;
    else
        printf("Iteration\n");

    if(a>=b)
    a=a-b;
    else
    b=b-a;

    return gcd2(min(a,b),max(a,b));
}
```

and the other one is by modulo operation

```
    int gcd1(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return b;
    else
        printf("Iteration\n");
    return gcd1(b%a, a);
}
```

i know that the number of iteration in gcd2 is more then gcd1 but in gcd1 i am using modulo operation which is also costly so i wanted to know are these two approach same in terms of run time .

Comment: Is there something that the [Wikipedia discussion on the complexity of Euclid's gcd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Complexity_of_Euclidean_method) does not answer? Your question indicates that you don't give a flying meow about complexity, and that it is the runtime performance for 'normal' input values which concerns you. If so, do you have any proof that either variant is too slow for your application? For specific applications - like cracking dumb protection schemes - it is often possible to leverage specifics into speedups of several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Also, there's also a third contender - the 'binary' gcd algorithm which involves shifting rather than division. This can be faster in certain situations. Without any specifics to go on there is little we can tell. Also, what's keeping you from running some benchmarks using representative inputs? This'll give you answers faster than twiddling thumbs and hoping that someone will do the work for you.

Comment: @DarthGizka what i want to ask is as we know the subtracting takes more iteration in most of the cases than modulo but we also know that modulo is more costly than subtraction so i was asking which is fast considering both these

Comment: The subtraction based approach is especially bad if one number is large and the other is small.

Comment: @Henry thanks for this

Comment: @Henry Knuth's version isn't so bad when the numbers are widely different because dividing by two reduces the numbers faster in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Knuth covers gcd extensively in Volume 2 of "The Art of Computer Programming" section 4.5.2

His version of binary gcd is more sophisticated and uses these facts:

a) if u and v are even, gcd(u, v)=2gcd(u/2, v/2)

b) if u is even and v is odd, gcd(u, v) = gcd(u/2, v)

c) As in Euclid's algorithm, gcd(u, v) = gcd(u-v, v)

d) if u and v are both odd, then u-v is even and |u-v| < max(u, v).

For his model computer MIX, binary gcd is about 20% faster than Euclidean gcd. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Can't we use these optimization in euclid's algorithum,i thing yes and then we can also make is quite more fast

Comment: If you are really interested in this I suggest you track down a copy of Knuth Vol II where he says "an interesting cross between Euclid's algorithm and the binary algorithm. If u and v are odd, with u>=v>0 we can always write u = qv +/- r where 0<=r<v and r is even; if r!=0 we set r=r/2 until r is odd, then set u=v,v=r and repeat the process. In subsequent iterations q>=3" - but since this hasn't replaced Euclid's algorithm in the textbooks I suspect the gain isn't especially valuable.

Answer (score 0):

For most practical purposes the version that uses the modulo operator should be faster, for two reasons:

(1) the subtraction-based version has to iterate more often and thus incurs more branch mis-predictions

(2) the modulo-based approach (and the binary version) are less vulnerable to the performance hitch mentioned by Henry, which occurs when one operand is much larger than the other

Also, the modulo-based and the shift-based version shift more work into specialised circuitry inside the processor, which gives them even more of an edge. The binary version is more complex to code; it can easily be made faster in languages that are close to the metal, like C/C++ or assembler, but not so easily in languages that are further away from the coal face. One reason is that C/C++ compilers can avoid some branches by employing conditional move instructions (e.g. CMOV) or at least allow equivalent bit trickery; compilers for other languages tend to lag behind C/C++ unless they share the same backend (as with the gnu compilers).

Things like python are a different story altogether, since the interpreter overhead dwarfs the instruction-level timing differences between additive ops, shift ops and mul/div ops, or the cost of branching (and branch mis-predictions).

That's a general view on things; it is always possible to construct pathological inputs that can prove any version to be inferior or superior.

In any case, [Dijkstra's dictum regarding premature optimisation](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil/) should be taken seriously. Barring proof to the contrary, the best code is the code that is so simple and clear that it is difficult to get wrong. Stick with the modulo version until you have proof that it's too slow. If and when you do have such proof, come back and we'll speed things up (since then there will be specifics known, specifics that can be leveraged).